# submit text box input using button

Tags: javascript, html

How do you submit text box input to a javascript function without submitting the server?

```
<input type="text" id="test"  value="" />
<br/>
<button onclick="submitMe(value typed into text box)" id="testButton" >Submit Response</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function submitMe(input) {
    alert(input); //should output text box input
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No need to pass by parameter, just the the element by id.

```
function submitMe() {
    var value = document.getElementById('test').value;
    alert(value);
}
```

Or you could pass the id like:

```
<input type="text" id="test"  value="" />
<br/>
<button onclick="submitMe('test')" id="testButton" >Submit Response</button>
```

js:

```
function submitMe(id) {
    var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
    alert(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<input type="text" id="test"  value="" />
<br/>
<button onclick="submitMe(document.getElementById('test').value)" id="testButton" >Submit Response</button>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pZ5T3/)**